# How to create a constructor which takes in a char array?

Tags: c++

I have a class, which take in a char array of size specified by a constexpr.

Message.h:

```
constexpr size_t InputBufferSize = 32;

class Message
{
private:
    char input[InputBufferSize];
    int size;
public:
    //constructor
    Message(char input[], int size);
    //deconstructor
    ~Message();

    int getSize();
};
```

I'm confused by how to define the constructor, and then create a new instance of that class using the constructor due to the char array. Here is my try (out of a few things I tried):

Message.cpp:

```
#include "Message.h"

Message::Message(char input[], int size) {
    this->input[InputBufferSize] = input[];
    this->size = size;
}

Message::~Message() { }


int Message::getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Message.h"

int main()
{
    char charinp; 
    char input[InputBufferSize] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f' };

    Message ms1(input[], 1);

    std::cout << ms1.getSize() << std::endl;

    std::cin >> charinp;

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to create a constructor with an array as on of its parameters, where the array already has a set size, and then create an object from that. The array to be passed into the object will always be of the same size, which is the size of the array the constructor is set to take in.

Comment: when you have compiler errors please include them in the question

Comment: Just use a `std::string`.  It makes life so much easier.

Comment: Change `Message ms1(input[], 6);` to `Message ms1(input, 6);`

Comment: i dont understand.. .you say the size of the buffer is given from the constant expression but then you want to pass the size as parameter along with the array. Do you want the constructor to accept only arrays of certain size or not? Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Message(char input[], int size);
> ```

The use of `[]` in a parameter declaration is just syntax sugar, the compiler will interpret `char input[]` as `char* input` instead.

> ```
> this->input[InputBufferSize] = input[];
> ```

This is not legal code. You need to use `(std::)memcpy()` or `std::copy()`/`std::copy_n()` to copy an array to another array:

```
memcpy(this->input, input, size);
```

```
std::copy(input, input + size, this->input);
```

```
std::copy_n(input, size, this->input);
```

On a side note, you should make sure that `size` does not exceed `InputBufferSize` before copying the `input` array:

```
size = std::min(size, InputBufferSize);
```

> ```
> Message ms1(input[], 6);
> ```

This is also not legal code.  You need to drop the `[]` when passing the array to a parameter:

```
Message ms1(input, 6);
```

> ```
> std::cin >> charinp;
> ```

On a side note, you can use `std::cin.get()` instead, and remove `charinp` from your code (since you don't use it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Message ms1(input[], 6);` in your main function,try changing it to `Message ms1(input, 6);`. 
The reason for this is that you have already declared the array `char input[]` and you have to refer it as `input`after you have declared it not `input[]`.

Comment: This doesn't fix all of the issues.